# How to list the cluster's id ?

Tags: vmware, vsphere, powercli, vmware-tools

how to get the cluster id in VMWARE PowerCLI or VMWARE SDK? I need to list the clusters and pick the id for a given cluster?

```
Get-Datacenter 
or 
Get-Cluster
```

Comment: please mark the answer as right if you got what you were looking for else, elaborate on your question. It will motivate other's to help others.

Comment: it wasn't really that helpful but you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 1

```
get-cluster | select ID
```

It will list the IDs of all the clusters with the header

option 2

```
(get-cluster).ID
```

It will list the IDs of all the clusters without the header

option 3

```
get-cluster MyCluster | select ID
```

It will list the ID of the cluster MyCluster  with the header

option 4

```
(get-cluster MyCluster ).ID
```

It will list the ID of the cluster MyCluster  without the header

Just run all these to know the difference

Answer (score 0):

In PowerCLI, maybe this? Not sure if that's the ID you're looking for.

```
Get-Cluster | Select ID
```